java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getBoolean(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Z in class Lsun/misc/Unsafe
I'm working in an Android Project that is targeting towards a device that runs on Android 5.1. We recently started to migrate from build.gradle to Kotlin DSL. The project has several submodules that it depends on and uses it as libs, they also recently had the same migration done.
After the migration was completed, we got a few issues. Mainly, we cannot run an apk that builds in debug. We recieve a runtime error whenever we try to run the apk on the device.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getBoolean(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Z 
in class Lsun/misc/Unsafe; or its super classes (declaration of 'sun.misc.Unsafe' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
at com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil$JvmMemoryAccessor.getBoolean(UnsafeUtil.java:634)
at com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil.getBoolean(UnsafeUtil.java:121)
at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.isFieldPresent(MessageSchema.java:4780)
at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.isFieldPresent(MessageSchema.java:4752)
at com.google.protobuf.MessageSchema.getSerializedSize(MessageSchema.java:1547)
at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.computeSerializedSize(GeneratedMessageLite.java:349)
at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.getSerializedSize(GeneratedMessageLite.java:334)
at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.getSerializedSize(GeneratedMessageLite.java:343)
at io.grpc.protobuf.lite.ProtoInputStream.available(ProtoInputStream.java:108)
at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.getKnownLength(MessageFramer.java:204)
at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writePayload(MessageFramer.java:139)
at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream.writeMessage(AbstractStream.java:66)
at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingClientStream.writeMessage(ForwardingClientStream.java:37)
at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream$6.run(DelayedStream.java:283)
at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream.drainPendingCalls(DelayedStream.java:182)
at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream.access$100(DelayedStream.java:44)
at io.grpc.internal.DelayedStream$4.run(DelayedStream.java:148)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

In one of the submodule that we are using and are implemeting in our module level build.gradle.kts is using GRPC and Protobuf, according to the log above, it tries to use a method provided by the Unsafe Java Class. I guess protobuf uses it when it needs to parse .proto files into objects and so on.
I tried to increment/decrement the GRPC, Protobuf java-lite, ProtoBuf plugin versions as i understand they need to be compatible, but that didn't work.
I've tried to install the same apk from Android Studio and through adb to a device that runs on Android 12 and it seemed to work.
The weird part about this is that, it runs on my Android 5.1 device if i set isDebuggable = false and isMinifyEnabled = true like so -
 getByName("debug") {
        isDebuggable = false
        isMinifyEnabled = true}

Then i seem to be able to install and run the application on the Android 5.1 device. But without, i get the error mentioned above. Is R8 obfuscating the part that causes the runtime error?
I'm not really sure if its a library compatibility issue or if something is wrong with the current setup of the build.gradle.kts. Unfortunately, i cannot share much of the code itself. Just wondering incase someone has tackled this issue before.
